# Install ubuntu on laptop ( works to be done afterwards)

Tags: drivers, partitioning

I wish to install Ubuntu on my HP Pavilion g6-2232tx Notebook PC. What should I do? Also where do I get all the drivers from after installing Ubuntu. My laptop has a graphics card and altec lancing spekaers. 4 GB RAM and 500 GB HDD.

Answer (score 2):

There is a guide [here](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/) that tells you most everything you need to now about choosing and installing ubuntu.

More then likely all drivers that you need are going to be installed when you install ubuntu, there is usually not a need to install any extra except possibly for your video card and wifi connection.

Video card drivers if you need to install one can usually be installed from additional drivers that comes with ubuntu, also the same with some broadcom wifi cards.

If you have any issues after installation then start a new question about that specific issue.

If you are dual booting in 14.04, wubi has no official support any more so do a normal dual boot and not a wubi install.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of information is already available on the Internet.

Check this: [Install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop).

If you want to use a USB drive, then follow the help listed here: [How to create a bootable USB stick on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows).